# How are you? in the beginning of e-mail?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Is it natural for native speakers to ask "how are you?" in the beginning of e-mail? Or it is better to delete to be concise?
Dear xxx,

How are you doing today?

xxx xxx xxx xxx....
I guess it is OK to ask, but this obliges a recipient to reply. Is it better to delete all the time?

Thanks,

Comment: I think it depends on the goal of the email (which you don't specify in your question, which is why I'm leaving an answer instead of a comment). If this is a friendly letter to your sister-in-law, there is no reason you can't add a "How are you?" up front. But if it's written to a company, it's often best to leave it out and jump straight to the point.

Comment: As @J.R. says. But also, when someone asks this of a stranger in an email, it can suggest that you are making an artificial attempt to be friendly, probably with the goal of selling something.

Answer (score 2):

You could start out with:

> I hope you are well.

It is a bit formal, but doesn't obligate the recipient to reply.

In informal communications or small talk, "How are you..." should be OK. Also such phrases would not be used if you have communicated recently.